# Threadsafety CurrencyManager

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, currencymanager

My datagridview is bound to a list, and I am adding items to the list in a background thread.
Do i need synchronization if I call CurrencyManager.refresh in the UI thread. That is, can refresh and list.add run concurrently without synchronization? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List<T>` is not thread-safe and you need to provide synchronisation. `ArrayList` has [Synchronized method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.synchronized.aspx)

Comment: i am talking about calling CurrencyManager.refresh when the list is being modified. I am not modifing the list in the UI thread.

Comment: CurrencyManager is reading the list while the list is being modified in another thread. The likelihood is that the list will get corrupted

Comment: Yea i am worried about that too. But CurrencyManager.refresh is currently very slow( with just 3000 items in list). So I really don't want to hold on to the lock for so long.

Comment: One option is to make a copy of the list before doing Refresh and bind to this copy.